# C# не видит system.web при тестирование метода на asp net

Tags: c#, asp.net, nuget

при вызове метода получаю такую ошибку:

```
System.TypeLoadException: "Could not load type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl' 
from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."
```

В общем решение два проекта: 1 asp net (.net framework 4.6), 2 mstest (net 5.0)
Код теста :

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void GetCompleted_byGuid()
        {

            //Тестовые данные
            string testGuid = "A4A3770D-8202-45FB-B972-A4AE487C37F9";

            //проверяем наличие КС
            Completed_Work_MAIN mainTest = Completed_Work_MAIN.GetCompleted_byGuid(testGuid);

            Assert.AreEqual(mainTest.user_in, "mstest");
            Assert.AreEqual(mainTest.idm_object, 387);
            Assert.AreEqual(mainTest.inn, 0);


        }
```

Код метода:

```
 public static Completed_Work_MAIN GetCompleted_byGuid(string guid)
        {
            var x = DB.DataSetSql<Completed_Work_MAIN>(SqlConnections.WorkflowConnection_Rengine,
               "select * from View_Completed_Work_MAIN  where guid = @guid",
               new Fields() { { "@guid", guid } }).ToList();
            if (x != null)
            {
                if (x.Count > 0)
                {
                    return x[0];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

DB - это (REngine.Database)
Без теста все работает отлично, но если тестировать его из проекта теста , падает в ошибку
Ссылка на asp net проект прокинута в тестовый , app.config сделать по примеру web, и тесты других методов с таким же подключением работают
Пакеты подключенные к проекту тест:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WorkflowProdConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="WorkflowConnection"    connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Base_DB_Connection"    connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ExternalConnection"     connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Дополнительные сведения о настройке приложения ASP.NET см. на странице
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433.
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="resources" type="DevExpress.Web.ResourcesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="WorkflowProdConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="ExternalConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="WorkflowConnection" connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Base_DB_Connection" connectionString="Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=ID;Password=Password"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    Описание изменений web.config см. по адресу http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    Следующие атрибуты можно установить с помощью тега <httpRuntime>.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Printing.v19.2.Core, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Office.v19.2.Core, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v19.2.Core, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxThemes.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v19.2.Export, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" maxRequestLength="4096" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="110" />
    <pages validateRequest="true" clientIDMode="Static">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
        <add tagPrefix="dx" namespace="DevExpress.Web" assembly="DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" validate="false" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <globalization culture="ru" uiCulture="ru" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v19.2, Version=19.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <devExpress>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="Glass" customThemeAssemblies="" baseColor="" font="" />
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="true" />
    <settings accessibilityCompliant="false" bootstrapMode="" doctypeMode="Html5" rightToLeft="false" checkReferencesToExternalScripts="true" protectControlState="true" ieCompatibilityVersion="edge" />
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl="" />
  </devExpress>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler extension=".cs" language="c#;cs;csharp" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:7.0 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701;612;618" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <compiler extension=".vb" language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008,40000,40008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

.csproj(тестового проекта):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile></DocumentationFile>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Auto</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
    <OutputPath></OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Properties\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Properties\**" />
    <None Remove="Properties\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.9.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="2.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.3.0" />

  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\тут путь\тут файл.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.dll.config" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="app.config" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)\testhost.x86.dll.config" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Скрин ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы начал со сравнивания .csproj обоих проектов

Comment: что я должен увидеть при сравнение ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема , как я понял была в том , что mstest использует NETCore.App, и это не подходит для (.net framework 4.6). Поэтому я просто перевел тесты с mstest на unittest под (.net framework 4.6), перенес все ссылки, и все заработало